# Computing a limit of a piece-wise function.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, piecewise-continuity

I'm a student studying maths, I'm taking a real analysis course and I'm looking through some old exams questions. I've arrived at a number of questions that ask me to take the limit of a number of piece-wise functions as $x \rightarrow 2$. Here is the first one.

$$f(x)= \begin{cases} 
      \frac{x^2-4}{x-2} & \text{if }x \neq 2  \\
      6 & \text{if }x = 2 \\ 
   \end{cases}
$$

I know if I do some algebra we get...

$$\frac{x^2-4}{x-2} = \frac{(x+2)(x-2)}{x-2}= x+2$$

So we get.

$$f(x)= \begin{cases} 
      x+2 & \text{if }x \neq 2  \\
      6 & \text{if }x = 2 \\ 
   \end{cases}
$$

so if we take the limit 
$$\lim_{x\to2}f(x) = ???$$

I'm not sure weather the answer is 4 or 6. They both seem intuitively correct so perhaps the answer might even be neither. I'm very interested to know!

Thanks for your time!

Comment: The value of the function **at** $x=2$ has absolutely nothing to do with the limit of the function as $x$ **approaches** $2$. That limit depends only on what the function does when $x$ is close to **but not equal to** $2$. Does that help?

Answer (score 1):

If you're not sure work the definition of limit. Let $\epsilon>0$.So if $\delta=\epsilon$, for every $x\in \mathbb{R}$ with $0<|x- 2|< \delta$ you have $$|f(x)-4|=|x-2|<\epsilon.$$
So you have that $$\lim_{x\to 2}f(x)=4.$$